# Two criteria MINIF and MAXIF formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I want the Youngest White cat's date from the excel table below to be displayed in a cell. The youngest would be born 29/07/2015.

In another cell i want to display the oldest white cat date 18/07/2015.

```
Column A ->Animal Column B ->Color Column C ->Date of birth
```

I know the formula if its is for one cell

```
 =IF(AND(A1="CAT",B1="White"),C1)


RowNo------A-----B--------C-----
 1------- CAT  White  20/07/2015
 2--------CAT  White  29/07/2015
 3--------CAT  White  18/07/2015
 4--------DOG  Black  29/07/2015
 5--------COW  White  29/07/2015
 6--------CAT  White  20/07/2015
 7--------COW  Black  29/07/2015
 8--------COW  Black  29/07/2015
```

Answer (score 5):

You can quickly get the pseudo-MINIF or pseudo-MAXIF using the newer [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF).

[image: MINIF and MAXIF using AGGREGATE]

The formulas in G2:H2 are,

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, ($A$2:$A$99=E2)*($B$2:$B$99=F2)*($C$2:$C$99), 1)
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, 1/($A$2:$A$99=E2)*($B$2:$B$99=F2)*($C$2:$C$99), 1)
```

There are a host of MINIF and MAXIF formulas out there but few that use AGGREGATE. This is a powerful new(er) function and deserves some attention.

This is a standard non-array formula that does NOT require <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.  AGGREGATE was introduced with Excel 2010. For pre-2010 solutions you can refer to [MINIF, MAXIF and MODEIF](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2013_release-excel/minif-maxif-and-modeif-with-standard-formulas/144a2f30-31ef-408e-86c3-f1443d9ac1fd).

Comment: Thanks for the quick and the best answer! U r brilliant!

Comment: [Glad to hear you got sorted out quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thanks for your work on this Jeeped, it has helped me with my own use of aggregate.  Why did you opt to use option 14 - large, instead of option 4 - Max?  I can post this a separate question if you feel it warrants.  I could not make max work.

Comment: @ForwardEd - Only *function_num* 14 - 19 provide(s) an **array** form of processing similar to SUMPRODUCT. I haven't played around with CSE'ing AGGREGATE on the lower function numbers but that may provide the same results. Asking for the LARGE (14) function with a *k* of **1** provides the same as the MAX (4) function without CSE. (see [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) for more on this)

Comment: @ForwardEd - Too many office workers 'break' CSE array formulas through double-clicking. I try to avoid the necessity of CSE as much as possible; even when they are marginally more efficient. e.g. `=If(low-match, If(medium_match, If(high_match, ...` requires less calculation cycles than `(low-match)*(medium_match)*(high_match)`.

Comment: @ForwardEd - Besides, replacing the *k* of **1** with `Row(1:1)`  means you get the first, second, third, etc simply by filling down.

Comment: @Jeeped I was reading that MS support article earlier.  Was trying to figure out why you would want to use aggregate option 4 instead of a simple max.  So far all I can think of is the options in aggregate to ignore errors or other items.  I too dislike CSE functions and try to avoid them.

Comment: @ForwardEd - I don't know if I would think it would be worthwhile to instruct someone on the use of AGGREGATE for all of its functions rather than expose them to functions that have been around since day one but I'm sure some SIWAMBA (**S**ome **I**diot **W**ith **A**n **MBA**) has decided so. In retrospect, I also consider AGGREGATE to be the 'half-finished' function. They could have easily cut down the calculation of full column references to the .UsedRange like they did with SUMIFS, etc (I do with UDFs I write) and made functions 1-13 array style.It's the little function that almost could.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot the data with animal and colour in FILTERS and date of birth in VALUES twice (Max and Min):

[image: SO31711671 example]